# error: n.imagesLoaded is not a function

Tags: jquery, templates

I have converted a template to wordpress format. and added styles and scripts in functions.php.  but i keep getting error

```
snow.min.js:11 Uncaught TypeError: n.imagesLoaded is not a function
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (snow.min.js:11)
    at Function.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at w.fn.init.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at e.t.initPluginIsotope (snow.min.js:11)
    at e.value (snow.min.js:11)
    at e.value (snow.min.js:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (snow-init.js:154)
    at __webpack_require__ (snow-init.js:30)
    at Object.<anonymous> (snow-init.js:140)
    at __webpack_require__ (snow-init.js:30)
```

my functions.php consists of

```
function evend_header_files() {
    wp_enqueue_style('university_gibberish_styles', get_stylesheet_uri(), NULL);
    wp_enqueue_style('custom-file', get_parent_theme_file_uri('/assets/css/custom.css'), NULL, microtime(), False);
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery1', get_parent_theme_file_uri('/assets/vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js'),NULL, microtime(), False);
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'sevend_header_files');
```

and

```
function sevend_footer_files() {
   wp_enqueue_script('isotope-file', get_parent_theme_file_uri().'/assets/vendor/isotope-layout/dist/isotope.pkgd.min.js',  array('jquery1'), microtime(), True);
    wp_enqueue_script('snow_min-file', get_parent_theme_file_uri().'/assets/js/snow.min.js', array('jquery1', 'isotope-file'), microtime(), True);
    wp_enqueue_script('snow-init-file', get_parent_theme_file_uri().'/assets/js/snow-init.js', array('jquery1', 'isotope-file'), microtime(), True);

}

    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'sevend_footer_files');
```

Require help.

The website template works fine in static with no errors but i keep getting errors in wordpress template.

TypeError: n.imagesLoaded is not a function and other errors too which are related to this one.

Comment: Can you please confirm that the order of including the scripts (from the page's source) is correct? So (1) jquery, (2) snow_min, (3) snow-init?

Comment: Yes they are .they are placed with (1) jquery with multiple other scripts ending with snow.min.js and snow-init.js

Comment: Which script defines imagesLoaded? It's not something I've heard of, and it's not the core jQuery either as far as I know. Are you missing another script that sets it up?

Comment: Solved the issue. Missed one script line (flickity.js)in functions.php. That solved the problem. Sorry, but thanks for all your help.